# Solspace Supersearch grid compatibility?

Tags: grid, supersearch

I've been looking but was unable to find an immediate answer within the Superseach documentation, but does Supersearch work with the new EE grid field?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comparison tool at http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/ Solspace suggest that **Low Search** would be the better tool for Grid or Matrix searching.

Details about Low Search can be found at http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search